# Appending HTML through Ajax Success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to know how I can append information through my Ajax on its success. This is what I have:

**HTML/PHP BUTTON:**

```
<input class="canjear btn" type="button" value="<?php echo JText::_('COM_CUPHONEO_BOTON_CANJEAR'); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $valor->item_id; ?>" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".canjear").click(function(e){
        if(this.tagName==="A"){
            e.preventDefault();
        }

//$(this).data("key") will return the value at the named data which is set by HTML5 data-* attribute
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&task=miscuponess.canjearCupon",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id:jQuery(this).data("id")},
            success: window.location.href = "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&view=miscuponess&layout=default"
        })
        .done(function(data){
            alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP FUNCTION CALLED:**

This is a big function but summarizing, it a query which returns data and besides other validations are made.

If you need more information please let me know

The information im trying to append is what I get in the `PHP Function` which is called in the Ajax.

Thanks.

Comment: `success: function(data){/* do something with data returned from server*/}`

Comment: Base on your code you are not trying to append any info but you redirect your page; so you need to use `.done(function(data) { /* APPEND YOUR INFO WHEREVER YOU WANT */})` take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Javad can I keep my `window.location.href` in my success and still append HTML in the .done function?

Comment: @Javad I have edited my code, its not entering the `alert`

Comment: No because by calling `window.location.href` you will load a new page and you will lose your current page, then how can you append your HTML to the current page? Can you explain why do you need to loading new page (may be the question or solution should be changed)

Comment: @Javad when the user clicks the `Subscribe` button I want to redirect him to a page where he will see the "item" to which he has just subscribed. Once here I need to notify the user about certain information concerning the subscription.

Comment: Then why not passing the the "item" or any other info through the query string so that after loading the page you be able to show proper info in the new page. I mean something like `success: window.location.href = "index.php?...&item=" + data` (I am not sure what's your data but you can concat the proper value you need)

Comment: You are using Ajax to postback a page prior to *always redirecting to a new page* showing the result.  **You do not need Ajax for this**. Just do a standard post/get to the server and let the server redirect to the new page. This is basic website behavior and not a suitable use for Ajax (which is for updating the current page *without changing to another page*).

Answer (score 0):

@MONZTAA

You are trying to use both the function which is alternate to each other.

***Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.***

In turn you should use only this :

```
$.ajax({

url: "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&task=miscuponess.canjearCupon",
type: "POST",
data: {id:jQuery(this).data("id")}
})
.done(function( msg ) {
   alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```